# Apache POI: Get more detail for formula error

Tags: apache-poi

My application puts values into a workbook with Apache POI and then evaluates formulas at that workbook. The formulas in the workbook are large: one contains a lot of references to other cells and those also contain formulas with additional references and so on. So far this works.

But when one of those formulas contains an error, it is hard to identify from which cell/formula the error comes from, because the error could be in the evaluated cell or in one of the referenced or in one of the referenced of the referenced (and so on).

With this code I get the type of the error (e.g. REF, DIV0, NAME, NUM, ...):

```
evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(mycell);
if (mycell.getCellType() == CellType.FORMULA) {
    switch (mycell.getCachedFormulaResultType()) {
        case ERROR:
            System.out.println(FormulaError.forInt(mycell.getErrorCellValue()).getString()));
            break;
    }
}
```

How can I get more detail about the error?

And more specific: How do I get the information where it comes from?

Comment: Have you seen https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval.html#Formula%2BEvaluation%2BDebugging ? That provides logging informations for each evaluation step.

Comment: @AxelRichter: Not yet. Thank you. :-)